# Could merge changes when deleting a record from Core Data

Tags: swift, database, core-data

I have some records in my Core Data database, and I want to delete one by its `NSManagedObjectID`. This is what I've tried:

```
context.delete(context.object(with: id))

do {
    try context.save()
} catch {
    print("could not save context: \(error)")
}
```

This manages to delete it in the in-memory database, but as soon as I call `context.save()` it tells me that it "Could not merge changes". I'm fairly new to Core Data, so I have no idea what this means. I've been researching it and it says something about merge policies, but I don't really know where to start.

I'm not sure if this is enough information to answer my question, but I don't know what else to put – this is the method which I've seen in numerous places online to delete records.

Comment: Do you have the object in memory? If so, why not delete it directly `context.delete(object)`

Comment: I don't - I just have the id. Surely though, `context.object(with: id)` would get the object, so it should have the same effect